# Keras&TensorFlow нейронная сеть не обучается

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

При обучении нейронной сети на вход подаются изображения в виде массива и правильные ответы. Само обучение срабатывает мгновенно и результат для всех данных в результате предсказания одинаковый. 
Фрагмент данных, которые подаются как правильные:

```
[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
```

Фрагмент массивов с изображениями:

```
[[ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.00392157]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 ..., 
 [ 0.00392157  0.          1.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.00784314 ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

Работа программы и предсказания:

```
Epoch 17/20
212/212 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.9579 - acc: 0.5047 - val_loss: 1.0571 - val_acc: 0.4953
Epoch 18/20
212/212 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.9437 - acc: 0.5047 - val_loss: 1.0584 - val_acc: 0.4953
Epoch 19/20
212/212 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.9352 - acc: 0.5047 - val_loss: 1.0588 - val_acc: 0.4953
Epoch 20/20
212/212 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.9420 - acc: 0.5047 - val_loss: 1.0583 - val_acc: 0.4953

Total time taken to train model: 4.23444890976 seconds

Evaluation of model on test holdout set:
212/212 [==============================] - 0s
[[ 0.30997425  0.32370323  0.36632255]]
[[ 0.31032962  0.32383287  0.36583754]]
[[ 0.30994558  0.32400697  0.36604744]]
[[ 0.30967158  0.32383308  0.36649528]]
[[ 0.30953971  0.32438737  0.36607292]]
[[ 0.30939212  0.3241998   0.36640811]]
[[ 0.30983475  0.32379121  0.36637402]]
[[ 0.30952132  0.32428694  0.36619174]]
[[ 0.30997089  0.32373276  0.36629626]]
[[ 0.31023106  0.32390219  0.36586678]]
[[ 0.30982301  0.32382965  0.36634725]]
[[ 0.31022772  0.32347488  0.36629739]]
[[ 0.30987772  0.32441998  0.3657023 ]]
[[ 0.30946305  0.32396272  0.36657417]]
```

Часть программы:

```
# Load training data, unpacking what's in the saved .npz files.
image_array = np.zeros((1, 38400))
label_array = np.zeros((1, 3), 'float')
training_data = glob.glob('training_data_temp/*.npz')   

for single_npz in training_data:              
    with np.load(single_npz) as data:
        train_temp = data['train']                     
        train_labels_temp = data['train_labels']       
    image_array = np.vstack((image_array, train_temp))
    label_array = np.vstack((label_array, train_labels_temp))

X = image_array[1:, :]
y = label_array[1:, :]

# Normalize from 0 to 1
X = X / 255.

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.50)

# Get start time of Training
time_training_start = time.time()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=38400, init='uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          nb_epoch=20,
          batch_size=1000,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Не специалист, но возникли два вопроса. Первый - изменяется ли результат при попытке увеличить число параметров сети (больше нейронов в скрытом слое, или дополнительный скрытый слой). Второй - раз уж изображения - возможно стоит использовать свёрточную сеть (или в этой задаче свёртка будет бессмысленна?)

Comment: Результат меняется, но всегда хотя бы один из трех параметров остается неизменным(на примере все три ). На с чет свёрточной сети не знаю, возможно стоит попробовать

Comment: Что за входные данные (и в каком виде) и что должно быть на выходе? Может что-то таки смогу порекомендовать.

Comment: Черно-белые изображения 320x120. В данном случае я их конвертировал в np.array и передавал сети. Как я понимаю, для сверточной нужно делать иначе.  Результат - массив из трех элементов, где максимальный элемент будет соответствовать 1, остальные 0. На самом деле этот массив обозначает три положения руля: лево, право, центр. Там, где 1 - нужное положение

Comment: То есть - такой вариант классификатора, выходит?

Comment: Если так - я бы сделал следующее - строил массив, в котором изображение представлено в двухмерном виде и скармливал свёрточной сети. Возможно, кстати - юзал бы предобученную, но тут уже не факт что это подойдёт.

Comment: И да - впрочем, ещё вопрос стоит ли тут юзать ИНС, или таки что-то из "классики" CV. Данных для обучения хотя бы сколько?

Comment: С данными не проблема, могу обеспечить любое количество. Сеть из cv пробовал - результат не очень хороший. Буду пробовать реализацию через свёрточную сеть